# Copying teams sites

Tags: site-template, team

Is it possible to copy a team site all its subsites and content,links etc to use as a template? One of our business unit has a teamsite which practically fits what we require with a few minor changes, I want to copy it and edit it to suite our purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I use SharePoint 2010, so I can't speak for 2013, when I attempted to do something similar, creating templates using OOB method 'Save as a Template', it was only possible to save a single site and content, no subsites, and there are a number of things it can't save see link below

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/save-a-sharepoint-site-as-a-template-5a4eb024-d1fa-4681-a4ac-e6bd1e3209ba

If your team site is a Site Collection, you can backup via Central Admin, create a new site collection in Central Admin with a different URL/database if required, then restore your backup to that location. This achieves the same result and keeps your subsites.

Use the Powershell command below to restore.

```
Restore-SPSite -Identity <Site collection URL> -Path <Backup file> [-DatabaseServer <Database server name>] [-DatabaseName <Content database name>] [-HostHeader <Host header>] [-Force] [-GradualDelete] [-Verbose]
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if trying to use OOB Save as Template, if the Publishing feature has been enabled on the Team Site, it is not supported for template creation. For example in my experience, things like the Content Query Web Part which is classed as Publishing feature, don't work straight away without going into each web part and resaving after you create a new site from the template.

As always with SharePoint caveats everywhere.